# Create a .make file task in Bamboo by using Drush for a Drupal project

Tags: drush

I'm setting up a CI system by using Bamboo. My aim: As soon as a change is pushed to the bitbucket server, the next task will create a ".make" file using Drush.

Bamboo is also found on the same server where Bitbucket server is. 
I'm working on a local machine.

My knowledge of build tools are as follows. If you want to make a Java build, you either use Ant, Maven or Gradle tool. You have to set the environment variables to the path for the build tool and JDK. The executable for Ant is path\Ant.bat.

I want to know how I can make the CI setup in Bamboo. What is the executable for Drush 7? I'm getting an error while running to make the build like: "Unable to find executable at **C:\drush\drush.bat**. Will try to run it anyway.
The system cannot find the path specified.".

I used the command type for the bamboo task.

The drush command I used was: drush make-generate name.make

**EDITED**: I'm using XAMPP on Windows. I googled and noticed Windows users having difficulties with the installation. I then followed the guidelines "Installing Drush on Windows".

1. Install Cygwin
2. Now install Composer for Windows
3. Install Drush the common way. e.g Drush 7.x stable:

   composer global require drush/drush:7.*

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/594744

I installed Drush using Composer so I don't know where to find the path to the executable. During the Composer setup I used the php.exe in the "path/xampp/php" directory.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) It sounds like you're asking where Drush has been installed on your system - we wouldn't be able to tell you that from here, you'd need to either search for it, or ask the person who installed it the path they used. If that's not what you're asking, could you update the question to make it a bit clearer what you need to know? Thanks